# How to mock sqlalchemy model create method in pytest

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mocking, pytest

I have an API which creates new flights in db, generating id and then inserting into db. I now need to mock this. Its an existing code so i don't want to change that.

```
     # create_flight.py (Existing code)

     from app.models.flight import Flight
     flight=Flight()
     flight.create_flight(json_data)  # need to mock this , 
                                       # this generates and commits in db and sets the flight object 
     response= { 'flight_id' : flight.flight_id }
```

My attempt of using pytest

```
   #conftest.py
   @pytest.fixture
   def mock_response(monkeypatch):
       def mock_create_flight(*args):
           class flight:
                 flight_id=str(uuid.uuid4())
            test=flight()
            return test
        monkeypatch.setattr('app.models.flight.Flight.create_flight',mock_create_flight)
```

it patches it correctly but i want the **flight** should have **flight_id** attribute set so that response dictionary sends the mocked flight id rather than going to db. I definitely doing something wrong here. not sure where. Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around it by importing the `sqlalchemy` model `Flight` in `conftest` , here is my solution

```
from app.models.flight import Flight
import uuid

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def get_flight_id():
 yield str(uuid.uuid4())

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def mock_response(monkeypatch,get_flight_id):
   def mock_create_flight(*args):
       flight = Flight()
       flight.flight_id = get_flight_id
       flight.version_id = 1
       return flight   
        
      monkeypatch.setattr('app.models.flight.Flight.create_flight',mock_create_flight)
```

This then returns mocked `flight` object in the original code